# iOS Crash related to UIFeedbackGeneratorConfiguration

Tags: ios, crash, uikit, crash-reports

In my iOS app release recently on Apple Store, I am seeing a crash related to something called `UIFeedbackGeneratorConfiguration` which I dont know what exactly is.

Below is screenshot from Xcode organizer.

[image]

When opened in Xcode using Open in Project... option, it opens like

[image]

The crash log when symbolicated is

```
Incident Identifier: 29848030-AD96-4039-8EFA-1B0F1C35718A
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             MyApp [53021]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D7C39FA7-6102-4415-9970-13B525FAD1D4/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.MyApp
Version:             4.0.0 (4.0.0.8)
AppStoreTools:       13A1030d
AppVariant:          1:iPhone8,1:13
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.MyApp [9019]

Date/Time:           2022-01-14 14:24:10.8109 +0000
Launch Time:         2022-01-13 09:55:28.3790 +0000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.1 (19B74)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    9.01.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000ce32ac21c
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000ce32ac21c
VM Region Info: 0xce32ac21c is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 44076548637  Bytes before following region: 12294897124
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO              280000000-2a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  GAP OF 0xd20000000 BYTES
      commpage (reserved)      fc0000000-1000000000 [  1.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Terminating Process: exc handler [53021]
Triggered by Thread:  0


Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000197f48474 class_isMetaClass + 4 (objc-runtime-new.h:485)
1   Foundation                      0x000000018249d1c0 -[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:] + 268 (NSNotification.m:490)
2   UIKitCore                       0x0000000183499438 -[_UIFeedbackGeneratorConfiguration _setupIfNecessary] + 336 (_UIFeedbackGeneratorConfiguration.m:255)
3   UIKitCore                       0x000000018363ff64 -[UIFeedbackGenerator _setupForFeedback:] + 44 (UIFeedbackGenerator.m:299)
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001833f73d4 -[UIFeedbackGenerator activateWithCompletionBlock:] + 56 (UIFeedbackGenerator.m:308)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001836fab14 +[UIKeyboardImpl applicationWillEnterForeground:] + 64 (UIKeyboardImpl.m:859)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d38c4c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20 (CFNotificationCenter.c:652)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180dcd554 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 48 (CFNotificationCenter.c:173)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180da2b34 _CFXRegistrationPost + 416 (CFNotificationCenter.c:199)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d4d754 _CFXNotificationPost + 696 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1147)
10  Foundation                      0x0000000182468138 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92 (NSNotification.m:560)
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001835a8b78 -[UIApplication _sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks] + 280 (UIApplication.m:11081)
12  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183256ae8 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke_2 + 1572 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:648)
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000018321202c _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 96 (_UISceneLifecycleState.m:109)
14  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183335b24 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 196 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:565)
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000018344bde4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 240 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:514)
16  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183677554 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 732 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:564)
17  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183607448 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 336 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:470)
18  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183212f14 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... + 188 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:73)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001832cee14 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 812 (BSAnimationSettings+UIKit.m:50)
20  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183214ca4 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 248 (_UISceneSettingsDiffAction.m:23)
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001832fa094 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 356 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:58)
22  UIKitCore                       0x000000018326ecb0 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.571 + 772 (UIScene.m:1807)
23  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183242ff0 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248 (UIScene.m:1508)
24  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183285244 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 264 (UIScene.m:1774)
25  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183210f18 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 464 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:80)
26  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019180ddac -[FBSScene updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 500 (FBSScene.m:549)
27  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000191825544 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 124 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:581)
28  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019180b704 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232 (FBSWorkspace.m:352)
29  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001918114f0 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 368 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:580)
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a6e198 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a10ac0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 220 (queue.c:489)
32  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019180cd6c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40 (FBSSerialQueue.m:157)
33  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019180c2f0 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 176 (FBSSerialQueue.m:181)
34  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001918103e0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 24 (FBSSerialQueue.m:194)
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180dc2210 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1972)
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180dd2238 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2016)
37  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d155d8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
38  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d1aa08 __CFRunLoopRun + 768 (CFRunLoop.c:2951)
39  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d2dd7c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
40  GraphicsServices                0x000000019afa29a0 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2200)
41  UIKitCore                       0x000000018356005c -[UIApplication _run] + 1080 (UIApplication.m:3493)
42  UIKitCore                       0x00000001832f5ce0 UIApplicationMain + 2028 (UIApplication.m:5046)
43  MyApp                       0x0000000104f52034 main + 68 (LAContextExtension.swift:12)
44  dyld                            0x000000010546c190 start + 444 (dyldMain.cpp:876)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ba7e1088 __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018b2008e0 nanosleep + 212 (nanosleep.c:104)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001824c49e0 +[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] + 152 (NSThread.m:504)
3   MyApp                       0x0000000104fbef58 closure #2 in AppDelegate.monitorNotificationSettings() + 276 (AppDelegate.swift:142)
4   MyApp                       0x0000000105024ac0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a6d194 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1517)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a6e198 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a101ec _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 728 (inline_internal.h:2601)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a1d42c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 340 (inline_internal.h:0)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a1dc28 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 172 (queue.c:6930)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1de48 _pthread_wqthread + 224 (pthread.c:2554)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9f0 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ba7e0b10 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ba7e1134 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d16ac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d1aba8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d2dd7c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x000000018246600c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001824a518c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001834ddd58 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 512 (UIEventFetcher.m:1167)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001824b2efc __NSThread__start__ + 792 (NSThread.m:972)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1f3a4 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9fc thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ba7e1088 __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018b2008e0 nanosleep + 212 (nanosleep.c:104)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001824c49e0 +[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] + 152 (NSThread.m:504)
3   MyApp                       0x0000000104fbef58 closure #2 in AppDelegate.monitorNotificationSettings() + 276 (AppDelegate.swift:142)
4   MyApp                       0x0000000105024ac0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a6d194 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1517)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a6e198 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a101ec _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 728 (inline_internal.h:2601)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a1d42c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 340 (inline_internal.h:0)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a1dc28 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 172 (queue.c:6930)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1de48 _pthread_wqthread + 224 (pthread.c:2554)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9f0 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ba7e0b10 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ba7e1134 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d16ac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d1aba8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180d2dd7c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181731f38 +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 424 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1372)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001824b2efc __NSThread__start__ + 792 (NSThread.m:972)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1f3a4 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9fc thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ba7e24a0 readlink + 8
1   Foundation                      0x0000000182541358 -[NSFileManager destinationOfSymbolicLinkAtPath:error:] + 92 (NSFileManager.m:5618)
2   Foundation                      0x0000000182540bf4 +[NSFileAttributes attributesAtPath:traverseLink:] + 60 (NSFileManager.m:898)
3   Foundation                      0x0000000182526c9c -[NSFileManager enumeratorAtPath:] + 40 (NSFileManager.m:4285)
4   GoogleDataTransport             0x0000000105368e98 __44-[GDTCORFlatFileStorage checkForExpirations]_block_invoke + 760 (GDTCORFlatFileStorage.m:425)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a6d194 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1517)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a6e198 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a140d4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 644 (inline_internal.h:2601)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a14b84 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 408 (queue.c:3937)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a1e750 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632 (queue.c:6727)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1de84 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2541)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9f0 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001dad937dc _Block_release + 96 (runtime.cpp:99)
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a6e4bc __destroy_helper_block_8_32c35_ZTS29dispatch_block_private_data_s + 92 (block.cpp:99)
2   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001dad93834 _Block_release + 184 (runtime.cpp:176)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a6e198 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a140d4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 644 (inline_internal.h:2601)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a14bb4 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 456 (queue.c:3937)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180a1e750 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632 (queue.c:6727)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1de84 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2541)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9f0 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9e8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dae1d9e8 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000ce32ac200   x1: 0x000000019b40aa0e   x2: 0x000000028141c200   x3: 0x000000019bb13775
    x4: 0x00000001e832ae08   x5: 0x0000000283a2c540   x6: 0x000000000000002a   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00003b6ce32ac200   x9: 0x00000001f6ddbfd0  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x000f00028065d000
   x12: 0x000000000000000a  x13: 0x000000028065d090  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x00000001f18996e0
   x16: 0x0000000197f48470  x17: 0x000000018249d0b4  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000028141c200
   x20: 0x000000019bb13775  x21: 0x00000001e832ae08  x22: 0x0000000283a2c540  x23: 0x000000028114c460
   x24: 0xfffffffd7ebe3dff  x25: 0x00000002834def40  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x000001990000021c
   x28: 0x0000000000001800   fp: 0x000000016aeb4f90   lr: 0x000000018249d1c0
    sp: 0x000000016aeb4f20   pc: 0x0000000197f48474 cpsr: 0x60000000
   esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault


Binary Images:
0x104f48000 - 0x10510bfff MyApp arm64  <dee02279d86431709c9bd750b7483261> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D7C39FA7-6102-4415-9970-13B525FAD1D4/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x105358000 - 0x105377fff GoogleDataTransport arm64  <f59376a7e76c3ca6b3062902b0029209> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D7C39FA7-6102-4415-9970-13B525FAD1D4/MyApp.app/Frameworks/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport
0x105454000 - 0x1054a7fff dyld arm64  <5e7ef5771cc5369aa04d28fbba883086> /usr/lib/dyld
0x180a0a000 - 0x180a8cfff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <56aa6e938d8e32feac73d3e79b1ba2f5> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x180d10000 - 0x18114afff CoreFoundation arm64  <ea9c1df294c7379bbf8d970335b1552f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1814e6000 - 0x18197bfff CFNetwork arm64  <d47c42c4e8f531babf5e074a91376b00> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x18244e000 - 0x18272efff Foundation arm64  <86d8a58db71f34c683e0014b2b835f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x183074000 - 0x1847fdfff UIKitCore arm64  <fb5c2d366a053355b898d8d3c163d02e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x18b1fc000 - 0x18b276fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <5700e26c19b735c9b739e62c325f4fcc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x191802000 - 0x1918a0fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <833f5b02d9623b8aa5d2335e0f7d25a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x197f41000 - 0x197f76fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <78e77e2874d0371aa2466d41374ba19a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x19afa1000 - 0x19afa9fff GraphicsServices arm64  <af306dd576573f63912fabc225106419> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1ba7e0000 - 0x1ba811fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <28a82cbdb2103662af9e636819d8909a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1dad92000 - 0x1dad93fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <56ddac7a396339f9aaad944023ad9d61> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1dae19000 - 0x1dae2cfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <ce7eb78851553c3888d812f1419fa5fa> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF
```

Please help if anyone knows what this crash can be about. I am actually a noob in crash reports analysis.

Comment: I was also having similar issue. And it's my fault not selecting (Any iOS Device(arm64)) but was selecting my personal test device. Building, with Any iOS Device(arm64) while building the ipa solved the issue for me.

Comment: I got a crash report like this too, only once so far so it's very rare. It has to do with using the vibrator. Do you make use of UINotificationFeedbackGenerator or UIImpactFeedbackGenerator?

Comment: I got mysterious crashes related to this, both in under 15.x and were in the App Store releases.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem on my end as well.

I mistakenly built the IPA with my test device selected. And I simply changed to **`Any iOS Device(arm64)`** as shown in the picture below. And no more crash.

[image: (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault]